# How can I combine the find command with other commands so I don't have to navigate to the folder?

Tags: command-line, python, find, locate

Sometimes I want to run certain files, but I don't want to navigate all the way to the folder.

If I know the file name and `find -name file_name.py` only returns one result, can I just use that?

For example, instead of navigating all the way to a specific folder and calling:

```
python file_name.py
```

Can I write:

```
python [ find -name file_name.py ]
```

or

```
python [ locate file_name.py ]
```

Or some sort of variant for 'search my entire computer for this file name and use it'? Preferably in one line.

Comment: locate wont have latest results.

Comment: What text editor are you using to edit these files? I'd suggest using a text editor that allows you to easily search for files under the current directory. For example, with vim and the [CtrlP extension](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) you could type `Ctrl-p` then `filename` to find the file. The case-insensitive *approximate* string matching it performs is called fuzzy matching and is a common feature in text editors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
python $(find -name myscript.py)
```

Comment: Ah! It was foolish of me to forget the `$`! I couldn't understand why brackets weren't doing anything. Thank you!

Comment: Using python $(locate file_name.py) is slightly shorter to type.

Comment: Shorter yes, but if I were in a project tree, I would find find . -name myscript.py, so I didn't get a copy installed globally and a dev copy.  So there's less variance in how I would use it those two times.

Answer (score 5):

Add the line `shopt -s globstar` to the file `.bashrc` in your home directory. (To just try this out, type this on the command line, it will only take effect in your current shell.)

Then you can use `**/` to mean “in the current directory or a subdirectory and so on recursively”, i.e. the same thing as simple `find` commands.

```
python **/myscript.py
```

Caveat: `**/` traverses symbolic links to directories, whereas `find` doesn't. In bash, you can't avoid this. In zsh, `**/` is available out of the box and doesn't traverse symbolic links (there's `***/` for the rare cases where you want to traverse symlinks).

Comment: This one is definitely the fastest to type (and probably my favorite too)! On the other hand, if your directory is bloated, it might be very long, since bash's globbing mecanism involves sorting out the files! in that respect, the methods involving `find` might be more responsive.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Sorting is fast, it happens in memory, in time Θ(n log(n)) which is close to the Θ(n) for reading. `**/` is a bit slower than `find` because `find` has an optimization that it doesn't call `stat` on files in leaf directories. Calling `find …| …` or `find … -exec … \;` is more responsive because files can be processed as soon as they're found, but `$(find …)` has to traverse the whole tree first just like `**/`.

Comment: This is also really convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that there is always more than one way to do things (even without using Perl):
`find -name file_name.py -exec python {} \;` 
will work as well. The exec option of find executes the following command for every file that it finds. In this command, `{}` acts as a placeholder for the file, and `\;` signifies the end of the command.

Comment: if you add `-quit` at the end of the `find` command, this is a good answer: `find -name file_name.py -exec python {} \; -quit`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ah, thanks for that. Yes, you may want the command to exit after processing the first file found.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the output of find to a variable and do whatever you want to with it as follows:

```
file=`find -name file_name.py` && python $file
```

`find -name file_name.py` will search for files named `file_name.py` and store the result into `file` variable and if the command succeeded(results are obtained without errors), python interprets `$file`.

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
xargs -0 python < <(find -name my_script.py -print0 -quit)
```

Now, as homework assignment, try to determine the pros, cons and differences of all the methods presented here.